# Problem installing google chrome

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome

I went to the google chrome website and downloaded the 64 bit .deb package from the site, after it downloads and opens the software center, when I click the install button it starts to install then it gives me this error "dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory", i do not understand why there is no such file when it says under the download page it says "this will add the add the google repository". Is there another way to install chrome or is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried opening a terminal and running `sudo dpkg -i packagename`, where `packagename` is the name (and path, if necessary) to the deb file?

Comment: You asked for the repository. In System settings go to Software & Updates , then Other software tab, then click add   and write  deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main  . Also, "http://" before dl.  It doesnt show up in my comment for some reason. Note the spaces in stable and main. Once it's added , edit it to type Binary

Comment: Found something else: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-linux-12-xx-13-xx/

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that Google Chrome can't install some of it's proprietary dependencies. You need to go to System Settings, Software & Updates, and check the check boxes to enable the Multiverse and Universe repositories. Then close the window, and you should be asked to update information about the packages. Click Update (or whatever it says) and it will close. Then try to install the .deb file again.

Comment: Any package dependencies Google Chrome has specified are not proprietary. The proprietary parts are included in their package itself.